# Pass value from webpage to web form in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to pass values from asp.net website to web form in asp.net?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question with additional information that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes. More info please.  You can pass values through the querystring or through a form post, etc.  It depends on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I have two applications, one is asp.net website and other is asp.net windows form. I want to pass some values from website on button click, call an .exe (output of windows form) and automatically fill the form. Is that possible?

Comment: "asp.net windows form" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the process via System.Diagnostics.Process, passing in the values from your webform as command arguument eg `Process.Start(@"c:\temp\myapp.exe -name=joe -color=green")`, but this will obviously only launch "myapp.exe" on the server.   I'm not familiar with your business processes, but surely you'd be better off save the values to a database in the web app, and then loading from the database in your windows forms app?